# userInfo is empty in continueUserActivity from Siri Shortcut

Tags: ios, sirikit, sirishortcuts, nsuseractivity

I've followed this excellent tutorial to implement donating Siri Shortcuts from my app:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/6462-siri-shortcuts-tutorial-in-ios-12

but I am unable to receive any custom data set on my `NSUserActivity`'s `userInfo` dictionary.

Using the sample app in the tutorial, I added:

```
    activity.userInfo = ["key": "value"]
    activity.requiredUserInfoKeys = ["key"]
```

to `Article.newArticleShortcut()`, but `userActivity.userInfo` is an empty dictionary in the `AppDelegate`'s `continueUserActivity`.

I tried the suggestions mentioned here (which are solving the same problem with Handoff), but they didn't help:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/9690

Has anyone been able to get this to work? I'm not sure what else I'm missing.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I was using this obj-c method to create my dictionary, and didn't realize they are specified in value-key order (instead of key-value order), that was my mistake:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary/1574190-initwithobjectsandkeys